# I downloaded node.js on a mac and I am getting "this type of file can harm your computer" from the pkg file

Tags: node.js

[I downloaded it from the node.js site directly, on an older macbookpro (10.8.5). I don't remember ever getting this message before from downloads.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeOHY.png)
I was going to email them about it, it might be something simple I am missing. Or this computer is too old (I can't download the latest xcode at this point, my computer is too old). Is it actually "safe"?

Comment: The screenshot you provided is from `chrome`. Whenever `chrome` detected that a downloaded file is executable (or a .dmg file or a .pkg file), it gives that warning message. The message is not coming from `mac`.

Comment: Ha thank you!!! I have downloaded hundreds of files, programs and packages before and never got that so I was concerned:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe they don't have a certificate for the installer :)

Comment: Thanks! yes I opened, downloaded it works normally:)

Comment: @Manuela - I swear the screenshot is eerily similar to `chrome`. But it's good that you found the certificate to be the culprit.